# Get value of column in dataset in javascript

Tags: birt

I would like to draw dynamic vertical marker line in my chart. Position of marker is available in dataset named `ml_data` in column `ml_position`. This is a dataset with one row and one column only. Is there a way how I can get value of `ml_position` in javascript? Currently I have the following working example:

```
function beforeDrawMarkerLine(axis, markerLine, icsc)
{
    importPackage(Packages.org.eclipse.birt.chart.model.data.impl);
    importPackage(Packages.org.eclipse.birt.chart.model.component.impl);
    var ml_value = 20;
    markerLine.setValue(NumberDataElementImpl.create(ml_value)) ;
}
```

The value is currently fixed (20). I would like to assign value of `ml_position` to `ml_value`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

My working solution:

Create global variable "mpos" and put your chart into simple table with one row a one column. Assign dataset with `ml_position` to table. This is important for executing dataset onFetch script before rendering chart. Finally set following scripts:

Dataset onFetch script:

```
reportContext.setPersistentGlobalVariable("mpos",row["ml_position"].toString());
```

Chart onRender script:

```
function beforeDrawMarkerLine(axis, markerLine, icsc)
{
    importPackage(Packages.org.eclipse.birt.chart.model.data.impl);
    importPackage(Packages.org.eclipse.birt.chart.model.component.impl);
    var ci = icsc.getExternalContext().getScriptable().getPersistentGlobalVariable("mpos");
    markerLine.setValue(NumberDataElementImpl.create(ci)) ;
}
```

Comment: Could you please let me know how to get data set  column values as String in beforeDrawDataPointLabel function ?

Comment: Thanks @Zadenek for you logic to create a global variable while fetching dataset and making use of it inside script. Was searching a lot for this. finally able to solve problem of dynamic coloring of series in chart with the help of this.